# Styling `ListView` menu with round corners

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, styling, listviewitem

I'm looking to build a menu using a `ListView` (I'm open to using anything else really that'll achieve the effect I'm looking for. The look I would like to emulate is the following.

[image: Google Calendar Menu]

Here is what I currently have for my XAML.

```
    <ListView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Decisions}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDecision}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Width="350"
        FontSize="12">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel 
                    Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border 
                    BorderThickness="1" 
                    BorderBrush="#DDD" 
                    CornerRadius="2">
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DecisionTypeNameConverter}}"
                        Padding="8"
                        Background="#EEE" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This produces an alright looking menu until I select an item. Once an item is selected it is surrounded by an ugly dark blue. How can I recreate this look (the gradient effect isn't required) in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to track the `SelectedItem`?

If not, I would suggest using an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx)

If so, you need to overwrite the selected item brush color so it doesn't show up. This is a system color, and I usually overwrite it like this:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
</ListView>
```

Comment: I do need `SelectedItem` and modifying the brushes works beautifully. This a little aside but how do I set a style for my background (for example) once the item is selected? I have a trigger for when `IsSelected` is `True` for `ListViewItem` that I would like to change the background color of my `Border` element. Setting the property to `Border.Background` in my trigger isn't doing the trick.

Comment: @Nosila In your `<Border>` tag, try setting the `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`. Then you can set a style trigger on the `ListViewItem` style which sets the background based on if `IsSelected` is true or not.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the blue selection rectangle you would have to set the [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) instead of the ItemTemplate. Consult the MSDN on [ListView Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx) to find out about the ListViewItem default style, especially the "Selected" visual state.

Comment: Thanks. Let me look into that.